# XML Live modification with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xslt

I want to know if it's possible to modify XML document and reload it without loose its changes in Javascript, i explain:

I hava one XML file with different data (custom objects). I display this XML in browser using XSLT transformation.

In the .xsl file i want to use Javascript to modify the xml structure when i click on a link to reload the page to show some informations from the xml, and hide some other information.

In my xml i have differents objects in differents types A and B.
Object of A type contains object of B type (some form of agregagtion) and many other text attributes. 
So in my first page i want so list A object with there attributes in a table. 
In this table attributes of type B is represented by a link, and when i click on the link i want to reload the page and show a table (or some other stuff) to represent B object, and only B object.

I think it is possible with Javascript, if i'm right when i click on the link i can remove all child of the root node i my XML and i append the B node, i reload the page and i display only the B node.

This is my JQuery script :

```
var glob_id;
var glob_rootNode;
var glob_nodeParent;

function reloadFromNode(rootNode,nodeParent,id){
    // Définition de variables globales
    glob_id = id;
    glob_rootNode = rootNode;
    glob_nodeParent = nodeParent;

    $(document).ready(  
        function(){
            var urlOfFile = window.location.href;
            // Chargement du XML a partir de l'URL du fichier
            $.ajax( {
                type: "GET",
                url: urlOfFile,
                dataType: "xml",
                // XML chargé 
                success: function(xml) {
                    //Ajout d'un listenr sur le noeud racine
                    $(xml).find(glob_rootNode).each(
                        function()
                        {
                            $(this).bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
                                reloadDOM();
                            });
                        }
                    );
                    // Parcours de tous les "nodeParent", fils de la racine 
                    $(xml).find(nodeParent).each(   
                        function()
                        {
                            // Si l'id du noeud correspond à celui du lien cliqué
                            var thisNode = $(this);
                            if($(this).attr('id') == glob_id){
                                alert('load success id :' + id );
                                $(xml).find(glob_rootNode).each(
                                    function()
                                    {   
                                        // On supprime tous les fils de la racine
                                        $(this).removeChild(0);
                                        $(this).removeChild(1);
                                        $(this).append($(thisNode));
                                    }
                                );

                            }else if($(this).attr('id') == ''){
                                alert('No id find');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    );
}

function reloadDOM(){
    alert("tree changed");
    $(window).trigger('resize');

}
```

And this is my xslt (its only the part which concern the A objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:js="urn:extra-functions">
    <xsl:template match="A">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>A Objects</th>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <td>attr1</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="attr1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>attr2</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="attr2"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>attr3</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="attr3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>attr4 B</td>
                <xsl:variable name="rootNode">composition</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="node">B</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:variable>
                <td><a onclick='reloadFromNode(&apos;{$rootNode}&apos;,&apos;{$node}&apos;,&apos;{$id}&apos;)' href='#'><xsl:value-of select="engines"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>attr5 B</td>
                <xsl:variable name="rootNode">composition</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="node">B</xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:variable>
                <td><a onclick='reloadFromNode(&apos;{$rootNode}&apos;,&apos;{$node}&apos;,&apos;{$id}&apos;)' href='#'><xsl:value-of select="enginesMap"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="attr6"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And finally this is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="composition.xsl"?>
<composition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="composition.xsd">
<A id="1">
    <attr1>35000</attr1>
    <attr2 id="2">
        <subAttr2>2</subAttr2>
    </attr2>
    <attr3 id="3">
        <subAttr3>9.5</subAttr3>
    </attr3>
    <attr4>
        <B id="4">
            <attr1>50</attr1>
        </B>
    </attr4>
    <attr5>
        <B id="5">
            <attr1>38</attr1>
        </B>
        <B id="6">
            <attr1>47</attr1>
        </B>
    </attr2>
    <attr6>the_name</attr6>
</A>
</composition>
```

For the moment i can listen root node modification (node 'composition') but when i'm reload the page with location.reload, the browser reload the entire xml and not the modifying xml.

Comment: Seems you modify the xml dom. But after that you need to generate the html dom.  Have  a look to `transformToFragment()`.

Comment: I will test this tks.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Javascript, and if i understand how JS work, when i display XML with XSLT in browser, document variable refer to HTML DOM and not directly to XML DOM, so if i want to modify presentation of information i must modify the HTML DOM isn't it ?
When i modify the XML with Javascript, change has no effect on page, but if i append some informations from the XML to a div in HTML DOM, the display change.

Comment: You have(at least) three possibilities. 1. Generate all your html when the page is loaded an show  hide pats of it onclick. 2. Generate new html from xml with JavaScript( [AJAX XML](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp) ) . 3. Build html with [client xslt](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)  and add the result per JavaScript.

Comment: I think i should use with client xslt but when i want to relaod xml with the same stylesheet nothing happend.